# How to save original div position() for later usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm currently running an animation sequence with the GSAP JS library.

After running the first instance of the animation, I run an `onComplete` function saving the current `position()` for `#myDiv`

I then try to use the `coordX` value in the last instance of my animation, however it just turns up as: **invalid left tween value: undefined**

Any ideas?

```
var coordX;

function regPosition() {
    coordX = $("#mydiv").position().left;
}

function animationStart() {
    //Initiate animation with onComplete
    tl.to("#mydiv", 0.5, {borderRadius:"50%", width: "35%", onComplete: regPosition})

    //Move #myDiv to another position than registered    
    .to("#mydiv", 0.5, {left: 1000})

    //try to use the original position stored in "coordX"
    .fromTo("#mydiv", 1.5, {left:-800}, {left:coordX});
}
animationStart();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `coordX` isn't set until `onComplete` is actually called after the first `.to` completes. Until then the value is `undefined`.

So the problem is that at *definition time*, the value of `coordX` is `undefined`, and that is the value you are assigning to `left`. So when that `.to` is evaluated, it sees an `undefined` value.

Perhaps a better way is to initiate the reverse animation within `onComplete`:

```
function animationStart() {
    tl.to("#mydiv", 0.5, {
        borderRadius:"50%", 
        width: "35%", 
        onComplete: function() {
            var coordX = regPosition();
            tl.to("#mydiv", 0.5, {left: 1000})
              .fromTo("#mydiv", 1.5, {left:-800}, {left: coordX});
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, good idea Vivin - that will make it work just fine, thanks for a lot for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some logical issues regarding timing. it takes some time to do the each step and your `onComplete` function won't be called until your steps all is done. do not user `onComplete` callback and just save your `coordX` before initiating the animation and use it when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, save the position intro this and use later..
i prefer .offset()...

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it was accompanied by a code fragment showing how to do this